# Show string values in eCharts heatmap

Tags: javascript, echarts

So I'm trying to display `"N/A"` in the cells for which I don't have any value.

The string values are hidden by default and eCharts doesn't seem to have any option to show them.

[Here is an example from the doc](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian) where the zero values are replaced by `"-"` but they're not visible.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use `label.formatter` to display the label you want, check this demo:

```js
let echartsObj = echarts.init(document.querySelector('#canvas'));
var hours = ['12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
        '7a', '8a', '9a','10a','11a',
        '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
        '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'];
var days = ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
        'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'];

var data = [[0,0, 0],[0,1,0],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,4,0],[0,5,0],[0,6,0],[0,7,0],[0,8,0],[0,9,0],[0,10,0],[0,11,2],[0,12,4],[0,13,1],[0,14,1],[0,15,3],[0,16,4],[0,17,6],[0,18,4],[0,19,4],[0,20,3],[0,21,3],[0,22,2],[0,23,5],[1,0,7],[1,1,0],[1,2,0],[1,3,0],[1,4,0],[1,5,0],[1,6,0],[1,7,0],[1,8,0],[1,9,0],[1,10,5],[1,11,2],[1,12,2],[1,13,6],[1,14,9],[1,15,11],[1,16,6],[1,17,7],[1,18,8],[1,19,12],[1,20,5],[1,21,5],[1,22,7],[1,23,2],[2,0,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,0],[2,3,0],[2,4,0],[2,5,0],[2,6,0],[2,7,0],[2,8,0],[2,9,0],[2,10,3],[2,11,2],[2,12,1],[2,13,9],[2,14,8],[2,15,10],[2,16,6],[2,17,5],[2,18,5],[2,19,5],[2,20,7],[2,21,4],[2,22,2],[2,23,4],[3,0,7],[3,1,3],[3,2,0],[3,3,0],[3,4,0],[3,5,0],[3,6,0],[3,7,0],[3,8,1],[3,9,0],[3,10,5],[3,11,4],[3,12,7],[3,13,14],[3,14,13],[3,15,12],[3,16,9],[3,17,5],[3,18,5],[3,19,10],[3,20,6],[3,21,4],[3,22,4],[3,23,1],[4,0,1],[4,1,3],[4,2,0],[4,3,0],[4,4,0],[4,5,1],[4,6,0],[4,7,0],[4,8,0],[4,9,2],[4,10,4],[4,11,4],[4,12,2],[4,13,4],[4,14,4],[4,15,14],[4,16,12],[4,17,1],[4,18,8],[4,19,5],[4,20,3],[4,21,7],[4,22,3],[4,23,0],[5,0,2],[5,1,1],[5,2,0],[5,3,3],[5,4,0],[5,5,0],[5,6,0],[5,7,0],[5,8,2],[5,9,0],[5,10,4],[5,11,1],[5,12,5],[5,13,10],[5,14,5],[5,15,7],[5,16,11],[5,17,6],[5,18,0],[5,19,5],[5,20,3],[5,21,4],[5,22,2],[5,23,0],[6,0,1],[6,1,0],[6,2,0],[6,3,0],[6,4,0],[6,5,0],[6,6,0],[6,7,0],[6,8,0],[6,9,0],[6,10,1],[6,11,0],[6,12,2],[6,13,1],[6,14,3],[6,15,4],[6,16,0],[6,17,0],[6,18,0],[6,19,0],[6,20,1],[6,21,2],[6,22,2],[6,23,6]];

data = data.map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2]];
});

option = {
    tooltip: {
        position: 'top'
    },
    animation: false,
    grid: {
        height: '50%',
        y: '10%'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: hours,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: days,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    visualMap: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        calculable: true,
        orient: 'horizontal',
        left: 'center',
        bottom: '15%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Punch Card',
        type: 'heatmap',
        data: data,
        label: {
            normal: {
                show: true,
                formatter: (param) => {
                    if (param.data[2] ===  0) {
                        return 'N/A';
                    } 
                   
                }
            }
        },
        itemStyle: {
            emphasis: {
                shadowBlur: 10,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            }
        }
    }]
};
echartsObj.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
      <header>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/echarts/4.1.0.rc2/echarts-en.min.js"></script>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
        </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

If you don't want background of 'N/A' data, change `visualMap.color' to achieve this like below:

check this demo:

```js
let echartsObj = echarts.init(document.querySelector('#canvas'));

var hours = ['12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
        '7a', '8a', '9a','10a','11a',
        '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
        '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'];
var days = ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
        'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'];

var data = [[0,0, 0],[0,1,0],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,4,0],[0,5,0],[0,6,0],[0,7,0],[0,8,0],[0,9,0],[0,10,0],[0,11,2],[0,12,4],[0,13,1],[0,14,1],[0,15,3],[0,16,4],[0,17,6],[0,18,4],[0,19,4],[0,20,3],[0,21,3],[0,22,2],[0,23,5],[1,0,7],[1,1,0],[1,2,0],[1,3,0],[1,4,0],[1,5,0],[1,6,0],[1,7,0],[1,8,0],[1,9,0],[1,10,5],[1,11,2],[1,12,2],[1,13,6],[1,14,9],[1,15,11],[1,16,6],[1,17,7],[1,18,8],[1,19,12],[1,20,5],[1,21,5],[1,22,7],[1,23,2],[2,0,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,0],[2,3,0],[2,4,0],[2,5,0],[2,6,0],[2,7,0],[2,8,0],[2,9,0],[2,10,3],[2,11,2],[2,12,1],[2,13,9],[2,14,8],[2,15,10],[2,16,6],[2,17,5],[2,18,5],[2,19,5],[2,20,7],[2,21,4],[2,22,2],[2,23,4],[3,0,7],[3,1,3],[3,2,0],[3,3,0],[3,4,0],[3,5,0],[3,6,0],[3,7,0],[3,8,1],[3,9,0],[3,10,5],[3,11,4],[3,12,7],[3,13,14],[3,14,13],[3,15,12],[3,16,9],[3,17,5],[3,18,5],[3,19,10],[3,20,6],[3,21,4],[3,22,4],[3,23,1],[4,0,1],[4,1,3],[4,2,0],[4,3,0],[4,4,0],[4,5,1],[4,6,0],[4,7,0],[4,8,0],[4,9,2],[4,10,4],[4,11,4],[4,12,2],[4,13,4],[4,14,4],[4,15,14],[4,16,12],[4,17,1],[4,18,8],[4,19,5],[4,20,3],[4,21,7],[4,22,3],[4,23,0],[5,0,2],[5,1,1],[5,2,0],[5,3,3],[5,4,0],[5,5,0],[5,6,0],[5,7,0],[5,8,2],[5,9,0],[5,10,4],[5,11,1],[5,12,5],[5,13,10],[5,14,5],[5,15,7],[5,16,11],[5,17,6],[5,18,0],[5,19,5],[5,20,3],[5,21,4],[5,22,2],[5,23,0],[6,0,1],[6,1,0],[6,2,0],[6,3,0],[6,4,0],[6,5,0],[6,6,0],[6,7,0],[6,8,0],[6,9,0],[6,10,1],[6,11,0],[6,12,2],[6,13,1],[6,14,3],[6,15,4],[6,16,0],[6,17,0],[6,18,0],[6,19,0],[6,20,1],[6,21,2],[6,22,2],[6,23,6]];

data = data.map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2]];
});

option = {
    tooltip: {
        position: 'top'
    },
    animation: false,
    grid: {
        height: '50%',
        y: '10%'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: hours,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: days,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    visualMap: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        calculable: true,
        orient: 'horizontal',
        left: 'center',
        bottom: '15%',
        color: ['rgb(255,0,0)','rgb(120,0,0)','rgba(255,0,0, 0)']
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Punch Card',
        type: 'heatmap',
        data: data,
        label: {
            normal: {
                show: true,
                formatter: (param) => {
                    if (param.data[2] ===  0) {
                        return 'N/A';
                    } 
                   
                }
            }
        },
        itemStyle: {
            emphasis: {
                shadowBlur: 10,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            }
        }
    }]
};
echartsObj.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
      <header>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/echarts/4.1.0.rc2/echarts-en.min.js"></script>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
        </div>
      </body>
</html>
```